# Select items from multiple lists via linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, select

I have the following issue:

```
class Base
{
   int val;
}
class A : Base
{
}
class B : Base
{
}

//Now I want to select from list of a and b
List<A> aList;
List<B> bList;
IEnumerable<Base> Find(int i)
{
//would need something like this
  return from a in (aList and bList) where a.val == i select a as Base;
}
```

What would be the fastest solution for this ? Should I join the enumerations afterwards or is that possible within the linq query ?

edit: Would .Concat be the quickest way ?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
return lista.Cast<Base>().Concat(listb).Where( x => x.val == i);
```

`Cast<Base>` is necessary to have a list of homogenous types, and `Concat` is the same as Union but will not incur the overhead of duplicate elimination.

Comment: You only actually need one of the casts

Comment: You can also use `Concat<Base>` instead of the cast.

Answer (score 0):

First off, use a [.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) method to cast everything and allow each collection to be the same type. This will only perform an explicit cast on objects already of the desired type, and return only objects of the desired type - I find it perfect for upcasting situations like this.

The second collection does not need to be cast, however - because of the definition of [`IEnumerable<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) uses `out` you can allow polymorphism to act on the second collection properly. See [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) for more info on this behaviour.

If you want everything returned regardless of comparison, use [`.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
aList.OfType<Base>()
.Contat(bList)
```

If you want each item returned only once, use [`.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
aList.OfType<Base>()
.Union(bList)
```

I Personally recommend `Concat` over `Union`, since it simply returns every element, whereas `Union` does the overhead of checking for duplicates, a task better suited to the [`.Distnict` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Union

```
return from a in (aList.Union<Base>(bList)) where a.val == i select a as Base;
```

> Produces the set union of two sequences by using the default equality comparer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx

**UPDATE**

Union will return all of the unique elements in both lists (that is, if the same element were in both lists, only one of them would be returned

> The Concat(IEnumerable, IEnumerable) method differs from the Union method because the Concat(IEnumerable, IEnumerable) method returns all the original elements in the input sequences. The Union method returns only unique elements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx

If this behavior is not desired, use Concat

```
return from a in (aList.Concat<Base>(bList)) where a.val == i select a as Base;
```

Comment: I don't think that will compile.

Comment: Would that be quicker than Concat ? Also, can I use union with two different list types ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper to do Where on both lists and union the results?

Comment: @DavidG: No, the iterator will simply run through both lists.  It will not create an intermediate, temporary list.

Comment: @jlew: It almost compiles.  I had to explicitly state `Union<Base>`.  Updated.

Comment: @DavidG: Both Union and Concat do deferred execution, so the performance is about the same.  Union and Concat differ in that if both lists have the exact same element, only one instance of that element will be returned.  Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @pixartist: You can use Union (or Concat) because they have a common base type (or implement a common interface).  Concat and Union have essentially the same performance (both defer execution), though Union is a true set operation in that it will suppress duplicate, identical elements.